# Bubble Chart with Line

Tags: powerbi

Are there any visuals available in Power BI that would allow me to create a chart that looks like this? I can create the bubbles with the scatter chart just fine, but I don't know how to get a line on it as well.

[image: Bubble Line Chart]

This was generated using the following data for bubbles, x-markers, and line values, respectively.

```
Label   Y     Weight  X
-------------------------
A      2.68%   30%   0.75
B      4.75%    4%   1.00
C     -1.37%   20%   0.68
D      3.69%   45%   0.30
E      3.02%   12%   0.62
F      0.00%    8%   0.00
-------------------------
X      2.33%         0.50
Y      4.30%         0.67
Z      3.65%         0.72
-------------------------
0      2.47%         0.00
0.95   4.46%         0.95
1      4.77%         1.00
```

Comment: Is the green line a trend line or is it defined by you? Power BI lets you add several different lines to a scatter plot in the Analytics pane (the magnifier between under the Visualizations pane).

Comment: @Joe It's not a trendline of A-F or X-Z. It has its own definition.

Comment: Late to the party, but did you find a solution for this? If not, would you like to provide a data sample?

Comment: @vestland I have not, though I wonder if something might be possible using the Analytics tab somehow. I've edited in a data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use R, this is certainly possible:

**Plot**

[image]

There are still some details remaining (X-axis tickmarks and red font color for negative y-axis labels, putting the line in front of the bubbles, and adjusting bubble sizes), but I'll look into that too if this is something you can use.

Just import the dataset below, insert an R Visual, and paste the following code snippet into the R Script Editor:

```
# Setup
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- dataset
#############
# Data
#############
df1 <- df %>% filter(Category == 'b1')
df2 <- df %>% filter(Category == 'b2')
dfL <- df %>% filter(Category == 'line')

#############
# Chart setup
#############

# Line
plt <- ggplot(data = dfL,aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_line(color = 'green3', size = 1.1) + ylim(-0.02, 0.05)
plt <- plt + scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent, limits = c(-0.02, 0.055))
plt <- plt + geom_hline(yintercept=0., colour="grey50", lwd=0.5)
plt <- plt + geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=X, y=Y, size = log(Weight), stroke = 8), color = 'lightsteelblue2')

# Bubble 1
plt <- plt + geom_text(data = df1, aes(label=Label),hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5) 
plt <- plt + scale_size_continuous( trans="exp", range=c(1, 20))

# Bubble 2
plt <- plt + geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=X, y=Y), shape = 'x', size = 4.5, color = 'red') 
plt <- plt + geom_text(data = df2, aes(label=Label),hjust=-1, vjust=0.55, size = 4)

############
# Aesthetics
############

# Remove clutter
plt <- plt + theme_minimal()
plt <- plt + theme(legend.position="none")
plt <- plt + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

# Axis format
plt <- plt + theme(axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "grey50"))
plt
```

I had to change your dataset just a bit, since I needed a way to identify which data that went into the line, bubbles and crosses:

```
Category,Label,Y,Weight,X
b1,A,0.0268,0.30,0.75
b1,B,0.0475,0.04,1.00
b1,C,-0.0137,0.20,0.68
b1,D,0.0369,0.45,0.30
b1,E,0.0302,0.12,0.62
b1,F,0.00,0.08,0.00
b2,X,0.0233,,0.50
b2,Y,0.0430,,0.67
b2,Z,0.0365,,0.72
line,0,0.0247,,0.00
line,0.95,0.0446,,0.95
line,1,0.0477,,1.1
```

Also, I hade to replace `1,0.0477,,1.00` with `1,0.0477,,1.1` to make the line straight.

This is what my complete setup looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I have yet to experiment much with R integration.

Comment: I really think it would be worth your while, and you can learn to do a lot of cool stuff in no time. The question now, with the introduction of Python to Power BI, is what to chose. Maybe both? And since you seem to have an extensive Power BI background already, should you learn more DAX or start learning R or Python? And I honestly don't know the answer to that. What I DO know is that I think that both R and Python is much easier for data analysis than DAX. With R and Python I've found that you can solve your problems step by step. DAX just blows my mind in all the wrong ways.

Comment: I've gotten pretty good with DAX, but it's missing some statistical functions like Excel's LINEST. If Power BI ever lets us use R inside of measures I'll be all over that.

Comment: Same here, or introduce some kind of DAX support that lets us run the expressions step by step more easily and study the output each step of the way. Or has that been introduced already?

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding the underlying data, you have 3 charts combined onto a single grid here: a bubble chart, a scatter chart, and a line chart. While not an unreasonable design, I don't know of any single visual (out of the box or existing custom visual from the Office Store) that's going to meet your needs to create the exact chart you have above.

That said, there are still a few options, none of which are that fantastic:

1. Write an R script that creates the chart you want, and then use the built-in R script visual to display it in Power BI. You can learn more about R visuals here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-visuals.
2. Build your own custom visual that does what you need (or hire someone to do so). There's a Getting Started Tutorial page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals
3. Vote for the existing idea to allow more flexible combinations of charts when the axis are shared. Existing idea here (but has only attracted 18 votes in 20 months): https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13647567-custom-combination-chart-types
4. Submit at idea on the Ideas forum for a new visual (if you think there's a compelling reason why your specific visual would be valuable to a broader audience, since Microsoft selects ideas based on votes). Ideas forum: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas
5. Compromise or change your chart design (e.g. split your charts into 2 or 3 side-by-side or find a way to show the data within a single chart-type).
6. Overlay a line chart on top of a bubble chart. It will be very difficult to get the axis to align perfectly. When you change the properties of a visual (such as hiding an axis), it changes the amount of space available for the main chart, which means it will throw off the alignment. However, if approximate is good enough, this may be an option. (If you plan to pin the visual to a dashboard though, then layering like this isn't a good solution.)

[image: 3 charts layered on top of each other]
*3 charts layered on top of each other: a line chart and 2 bubble charts, all with the same fixed scale. Note: alignment is not perfect, and I didn't have access to the underlying data used in the question so the values are approximate too.*

**Recommendation**

Personally, I would recommend exploring R as the best next step. It's a very flexible programming language that should be able to recreate what you want in a built-in & supported way. (Exactly how to recreate it in R isn't something I can answer though.)

Comment: Thank you. If X, Y, and Z were also bubbles, just a different color, would that simplify anything?

Comment: Not really, because you still have the line & bubble combination (and the line is calculated independently from the bubbles). There's no visual that fulfills those requirements right now.